# Displaying 3 leaflet maps on same page

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I have followed many tutorials about displaying two leaflet maps on the same page. My ultimate goal would be to have a php file that I could pass an address to and it would return a div with a map in it, but for now I'm just trying to get 3 maps to appear on the same page. It'll work with two, but not with three, and I am going bald trying to figure this out!
Any thoughts on why the first two maps will show, but not the third?

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="map-wrapper">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="map-wrapper">
<div id="map_canvas2"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="map-wrapper">
<div id="map_canvas3"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var firefoxIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'pin2.png',
iconAnchor: [14, 48]
});

var map = L.map('map_canvas').setView([40.744996, -73.983761], 16);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([40.744996, -73.983761], {icon: firefoxIcon}).addTo(map);

var map2 = L.map('map_canvas2').setView([38.895856, -77.009787], 16);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map2);
var marker = L.marker([38.895856, -77.009787], {icon: firefoxIcon}).addTo(map2);

var map3 = L.map('map_canvas3').setView([40.870100, -73.458890], 16);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map3);
var marker = L.marker([40.870100, -73.458890], {icon: firefoxIcon}).addTo(map3);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Add class "map" to your "map_canvas" elements.

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="map-wrapper">
<div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="map-wrapper">
<div class="map" id="map_canvas2"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<div class="map-wrapper">
<div class="map" id="map_canvas3"></div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var firefoxIcon = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'pin2.png',
iconAnchor: [14, 48]
});

var map = L.map('map_canvas').setView([40.744996, -73.983761], 16);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([40.744996, -73.983761], {icon: firefoxIcon}).addTo(map);

var map2 = L.map('map_canvas2').setView([38.895856, -77.009787], 16);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map2);
var marker = L.marker([38.895856, -77.009787], {icon: firefoxIcon}).addTo(map2);

var map3 = L.map('map_canvas3').setView([40.870100, -73.458890], 16);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map3);
var marker = L.marker([40.870100, -73.458890], {icon: firefoxIcon}).addTo(map3);
</script>
```

And in your css file add this style:

```
.map {
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px
}
```

It will work. Tested in jfiddle.